# Solved - pdf-lib.js Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to parse PDF document (line:0 col:0 offset=0): No PDF header found

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-lib.js

im using pdf-lib.js lib but im having troubles, this code was working but some day give me that error
Note: the pdf is in the same route

when i press the button the pdf get downloaded but without any text just the same pdf as the original

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF-lib.js Prueba</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib@1.4.0/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<button id="agregarTexto">Agregar Texto</button>

<script src="pdf.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

document.getElementById('agregarTexto').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch('Prueba.pdf').then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    const firstPage = pages[0];

    const arialFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(PDFLib.StandardFonts.Helvetica);
    firstPage.drawText('Hola', {
        x: 105,
        y: 698,
        font: arialFont,
        size: 11,
        color: PDFLib.rgb(0, 0, 0),
    });

    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'pruebapdf_modificado.pdf';
    a.textContent = 'Descargar PDF Modificado';
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
});
```

Comment: Code doesn't just stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the error was the integration of Internet Download Manager before the PDF was edited IDM catch the PDF  and it did not allow the PDF to reach the Js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).